# Is there a way to write an Expression in Power Automate to retrieve item from SurveyMonkey?

Tags: expression, power-automate, surveymonkey

There is no dynamic content you can get from the SurveyMonkey trigger in Power Automate except for the Analyze URL, Created Date, and Link.  Is it possible I could retrieve the data with an expression so I could add fields to SharePoint or send emails based on answers to questions?

For instance, here is some JSON data for a county multiple choice field, that I would like to know the county so I can have the email sent to the correct person:
{
"id": "753498214",
"answers": [
{
"choice_id": "4963767255",
"simple_text": "Williamson"
}
],
"family": "single_choice",
"subtype": "menu",
"heading": "County where the problem is occurring:"
}

And basically, a way to create dynamic fields from the content so it would be more usable?
I am a novice so your answer will have to assume I know nothing!
Thanks for considering the question.

Overall, anything I have tried is unsuccessful!

Comment: You can do anything, so the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get an answer on Microsoft Power Users support.

Put this data in compose action:
{

```
"id": "753498214",

"answers": [

  {

    "choice_id": "4963767255",

    "simple_text": "Williamson"

  }

],

"family": "single_choice",

"subtype": "menu",

"heading": "County where the problem is occurring:"
```

}

Then these expressions in additional compose actions:

To get choice_id:
outputs('Compose')?['answers']?[0]?['choice_id']

To get simple_text:
outputs('Compose')?['answers']?[0]?['simple_text']

Reference link here where I retrieved the answer is here.
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/How-to-write-an-expression-to-retrieve-answer/m-p/1960784#M114215